# Verify the image using selenium webdriver

Tags: image, selenium

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='divLogo']/img"));
boolean ImagePresent = (boolean)JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].complete && typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth != \"undefined\" && arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0",image);
if (!ImagePresent) {
System.out.println("Image not displayed.");
 } else {
    System.out.println("Image displayed.");
     }
```

can anyone explain the above code.

Comment: What is your attempt at an interpretation?  No need for us to preach what you already know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line finds the WebElement image using the given XPath.

The next line executes some javascript and returns the result to ImagePresent.

The Javascript checks if **image** (arguments[0]) has completed loading AND its naturalWidth is not "undefined" AND its naturalWidth is greater than zero. In other words, it checks if it is loaded AND wider than nothing :)

The if block checks ImagePresent (the result of the Javascript). If it's false it prints out "Image not displayed.". If it is true it prints "Image displayed."

Comment: No problem :) I'm new too. Surely you should be able to mark this as the answer to your own question though? Would kinds put a damper on answering questions from users with a low rep otherwise.